# Urdu Font Declaration On Wikipedia

Tags: font-face, wikipedia

Wikipedia has lately installed a very aesthetic mainstream Urdu font called Jameel Noori Nastaleeq.

I wanted to learn about the @font-face declarations for this font, but failed to located them in the referenced stylesheets.

Can somebody help me in locating the font face declarations for Jameel Noori Nastaleeq on Wikipedia? One page where the font has been used is [This Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mustansar_Hussain_Tarar). The font in discussion is used on the first line under From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia.

Answer (score 1):

It's right in page source:

`<span lang="ur" dir="rtl"><span class="Nastaliq" title="Urdu Nastaliq" style="font-size: 125%; font-family: 'Jameel Noori Nastaleeq', 'Urdu Typesetting', 'Noto Nastaliq Urdu', 'Noto Nastaliq Urdu Draft', 'Hussaini Nastaleeq', 'AlQalam Taj Nastaleeq', IranNastaliq, 'Nafees Nastaleeq', 'Nafees Nastaleeq v1.01', Nafees, 'Pak Nastaleeq', 'PDMS_Jauhar', 'Alvi Lahori Nastaleeq';">مستنصر حسين تارڑ</span></span>`

Looking at [page wikitext](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Mustansar_Hussain_Tarar&action=edit), the inner span that has the list of fonts comes from [`Template:Script/Nastaliq`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Script/Nastaliq) ([view source](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Template:Script/Nastaliq&action=edit)).

Comment: +1 for helpful post. But I don't see any @font-face declaration anywhere in the cited location. Or am I missing something?